# Oozie Java API Kerberos Authentication

Tags: java, hadoop, kerberos, oozie

I am trying to get an oozie job status using oozie java API. Currently it is failing with the message
Exception in thread "main" HTTP error code: 401 : Unauthorized

We are using a kerberos authentication in our cluster with a keytab file.
Please guide as how to proceed to implement the authentication.

My current program is:

```
import org.apache.oozie.client.OozieClient;

public class oozieCheck
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // get a OozieClient for local Oozie
        OozieClient wc = new OozieClient(
                "http://myserver:11000/oozie");

        System.out.println(wc.getJobInfo(args[1]));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured a way to use kerberos in my java api.

First obtain kerberos tgt.

Then the below code works:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.oozie.client.AuthOozieClient;
import org.apache.oozie.client.WorkflowJob.Status;

public class Wrapper
{
    public static AuthOozieClient wc = null;
    public static String OOZIE_SERVER_URL="http://localhost:11000/oozie";

   public Wrapper ( String oozieUrlStr ) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        URL oozieUrl = new URL(oozieUrlStr);
        // get a OozieClient for local Oozie
        wc = new AuthOozieClient(oozieUrl.toString());
    }

    public static void main ( String [] args )
    {
        String lineCommon;
        String jobId = args[0]; // The first argument is the oozie jobid

        try
        {
            Wrapper client = new Wrapper(OOZIE_SERVER_URL);
            Properties conf = wc.createConfiguration();

            if(wc != null)
            {
                // get status of jobid from CLA
                try
                {
                    while (wc.getJobInfo(jobId).getStatus() == Status.RUNNING)
                    {
                        logger.info("Workflow job running ...");
                        logger.info("Workflow job ID:["+jobId+"]");
                    }
                    if(wc.getJobInfo(jobId).getStatus() == Status.SUCCEEDED)
                    {
                        // print the final status of the workflow job
                        logger.info("Workflow job completed ...");
                        logger.info(wc.getJobInfo(jobId));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    // print the final status of the workflow job
                    logger.info("Workflow job Failed ...");
                    logger.info(wc.getJobInfo(jobId));
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.exit(9999);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to patch the oozie client if docs do not mention Kerberos.

Comment: Kerberos is mentioned in the oozie docs but there is no example and I am unable to figure how to put it all together.

Comment: File a ticket for bad documentation and examine the code what they do. I would assume that they are using GSS-API without JAAS.

Comment: The class `org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator` implements kerberos authentication for oozie java API but I need an example to follow to make it work.